# How to make a custom converter for fields in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a label and a textfield and it will display two different values.

```
if(a != null && b == null) {
   return "a"; 
}
else if(a == null && b != null) {
   return "b"; 
}
```

The logic is quite simple, but how to fit this in xaml and mvvm-pattern? I have a viewmodel and a view (xaml-ui). The code should propably be placed in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youe mean to say.... you want to diplay **a** for first condition and **b** for second condition ??

if Thats true...

then ..

Make a property with Property chnaged notification in your ViewModel

## Code inside your ViewModel

```
public void ValidationFunction
{
    if(a != null && b == null) 
    {
          TextToDisplay ="a";
    }
    else if(a == null && b != null) 
    {
          TextToDisplay ="b";
    }
    else
    {
          TextToDisplay= string.Empty;
    } 
}
```

## Binding in XAML

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=TextToDisplay}/>
```

Dont forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Setter of property.

Call the validation function when required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) on A and B, and implement your logic in a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
      <Binding Path="A"/>
      <Binding Path="B"/>
    </MultiBinding/>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: The question stated MVVM which should largely remove the need for converters - is it not better to put logic in ViewModel? (the question not that clear - maybe I missunderstood it)

Comment: The both seems valid to me. It all depends if it's an aesthetical or usability choice, in which case it belongs to the view (multibinding and converter) or if it's a more "logic" choice (viewmodel or model).

Comment: Actually doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
class MyViewModel {
    string ResultStr {
        get {
            if (a != null && b == null)
                return "a"; 
            else if (a == null && b != null)
                return "b"; 
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=ResultStr Mode=OneWay}/>
```